# How do I read, loop, compare, manipulate and write CSV File in Python 2 correct

Tags: python, excel, csv, for-loop, data-manipulation

I tried a lot now, and also read a lot the past days, but I can't come up with a correct solution to my problem. Maybe someone can give me helping hand.

I have to CSV Files where wdw_clip_db_2018-01-17_2 (4720 lines) should have all data and wdw_content_complete (2752 lines) only a subset.

wdw_clip_db_2018-01-17_2.csv:

```
11,0_7cjgob0v,9000301_AzubiGlueckT1.mxf,0_7cjgob0v.mpg  
43,0_heor15yl,,0_heor15yl.mpg  
1616,0_dfopff5t,578_Bier.MXF,0_dfopff5t.mpg  
1500,0_9fpl1ozv,601_SinnestŠuschungen.MXF,0_9fpl1ozv.mpg  
1931,0_cbx3zgw6,9070201_KeinGeldFuerGeschen.mxf,0_cbx3zgw6.mpg
```

wdw_content_complete.csv:

```
1737,9000301_AzubiGlueckT1.mxf,0_7cjgob0v  
1451,578_Bier.MXF,0_dfopff5t  
1433,445_Holzverarbeitung.MXF,NULL  
1461,601_Sinnestäuschungen.MXF,NULL  
1762,9070201_KeinGeldFuerGeschen.mxf,NULL
```

What I need to come up with is are the following csv files readable by Excel:

wdw_clean_assets.csv:

```
9000301_AzubiGlueckT1.mxf,0_7cjgob0v  
578_Bier.MXF,0_dfopff5t
```

Where wdw_clean_assets holds every line which matches the file and the external_refernce (e.g. 0_7cjgob0v).

wdw_to_add_ext_refs.csv:

```
9070201_KeinGeldFuerGeschen.mxf,0_cbx3zgw6
```

Where wdw_to_add_ext_refs holds every line which matches the file but has a NULL in the external_reference field. The NULL is replaced with the external reference found in wdw_clip_db_2018-01-17_2.csv.

When I compare the number of lines, there seam to be lines in wdw_content_complete.csv which are not in wdw_clip_db_2018-01-17_2.csv. To be honest this shouldn't be so I need to find out what's wrong with these lines. Therefore I need to put the Rest of wdw_content_complete.csv in a new CSV file.

wdw_to_clean_assets.csv:

```
1433,445_Holzverarbeitung.MXF,NULL  
1461,601_Sinnestäuschungen.MXF,NULL
```

And finally I need the Rest of both CSVs wdw_clip_db_2018-01-17_2.csv and wdw_content_complete.csv in two separate CSVs. Therefore I tried to somehow substract one list from another which unfortunately also doesn't work correct.

wdw_hansi_assets_rest.csv:

```
1500,0_9fpl1ozv,601_SinnestŠuschungen.MXF,0_9fpl1ozv.mpg
```

wdw_mediahub_assets_rest.csv:

```
1433,445_Holzverarbeitung.MXF,NULL
```

What I got so far is this Python Script:

import csv

```
# CSV Files
# wdw_clip_db_2018-01-17_2.csv
# wdw_content_complete.csv

# Reading the CSV Files
hansi_assets = []

with open('wdw_clip_db_2018-01-17_2.csv') as hansi_db:
    reader = csv.reader(hansi_db)
    for row in reader:
        hansi_assets.append(row)

hansi_db.close()

mediahub_assets = []

with open('wdw_content_complete.csv') as mediahub_db:
    reader = csv.reader(mediahub_db)
    for row in reader:
        mediahub_assets.append(row)

mediahub_db.close()

clean_asset = []
clean_assets = []
to_add_ext_ref = []
to_add_ext_refs = []
to_clean_assets = []
hansi_assets_rest = []
mediahub_assets_rest = []
hansi_assets_rm = []
mediahub_assets_rm = []
num_clean_rwos = 0
num_to_clean_rows = 0
num_to_add_ext_refs = 0
num_dirty_rows = 0
num_hansi_iterations = 0
num_mediahub_iterations = 0
num_mediahub_null = 0
num_hansi_mediahub_matches = 0

# Looping over the CSV Files
for hansi_asset in hansi_assets:
    num_hansi_iterations += 1

    for mediahub_asset in mediahub_assets:
        num_mediahub_iterations += 1

        # Checking if there are similar, clean entries
        if hansi_asset[2] == mediahub_asset[1] or hansi_asset[3] == mediahub_asset[1] and hansi_asset[1] == mediahub_asset[2]:
            clean_assets.append(mediahub_asset)

            # Counting for evaluation reasons
            num_clean_rwos += 1
            mediahub_assets_rm.append(mediahub_asset)
            hansi_assets_rm.append(hansi_asset)

        # Checking if there are entries which miss the Ext_Ref field and replacing the NULL by the corresponding Ext_Ref in the hansi_asset
        elif hansi_asset[2] == mediahub_asset[1] or hansi_asset[3] == mediahub_asset[1] and mediahub_asset[2] == "NULL":
            to_add_ext_ref = [mediahub_asset[1], hansi_asset[1]]
            to_add_ext_refs.append(to_add_ext_ref)

            # Counting for evaluation reasons
            num_to_add_ext_refs += 1
            mediahub_assets_rm.append(mediahub_asset)
            hansi_assets_rm.append(hansi_asset)

        # Checking if there are entries that don't match
        elif hansi_asset[2] != mediahub_asset[1] or hansi_asset[3] != mediahub_asset[1]:
            to_clean_assets.append([mediahub_asset[1], mediahub_asset[2]])

            # Counting for evaluation reasons
            num_to_clean_rows += 1

            # Creating a list to substract from its origin to get the Rest
            mediahub_assets_rm.append(mediahub_asset)
            hansi_assets_rm.append(hansi_asset)


# Just counting the Matches
for hansi_asset in hansi_assets:
    for mediahub_asset in mediahub_assets:
        if hansi_asset[2] == mediahub_asset[1] or hansi_asset[3] == mediahub_asset[1]:
            num_hansi_mediahub_matches += 1


# Just counting the NULLs
for mediahub_asset in mediahub_assets:
    num_mediahub_iterations += 1
    if mediahub_asset[2] == "NULL":
        num_mediahub_null += 1


#   for mediahub_asset_rm in mediahub_assets_rm:
#       if mediahub_asset[1] != mediahub_asset_rm[1]:
#           mediahub_assets_rest = Diff(mediahub_assets, mediahub_assets_rm)

# Trying to substract medihub_assets_rm from mediahub_assets to get the Rest
mediahub_assets_rest = [item for item in mediahub_assets_rm if item not in mediahub_assets]
hansi_assets_rest = [item for item in hansi_assets_rm if item not in hansi_assets]


# Printing some lines for evaluation
print hansi_assets[1]
print mediahub_assets[1]
print clean_assets[1]
print to_clean_assets[1]
print to_add_ext_refs[1]
print hansi_assets_rest[1]
print mediahub_assets_rest[1]
print hansi_assets_rm[1]
print mediahub_assets_rm[1]
print "Num Hansi Assets: " + str(len(hansi_assets))
print "Num Mediahub Assets: " + str(len(mediahub_assets))
print "Num Clean Assets: " + str(len(clean_assets))
print "Num Hansi Assets to remove: " + str(len(hansi_assets_rm))
print "Num Mediahub Assets to remove: " + str(len(mediahub_assets_rm))
print "Num Hansi Rest Assets: " + str(len(hansi_assets_rest))
print "Num Mediahub Rest Assets: " + str(len(mediahub_assets_rest))
print "Num Mediahub NULLs: " + str(num_mediahub_null)
print "Num Hansi Mediahub Matches: " + str(num_hansi_mediahub_matches)
print "Num Clean Rows: " + str(num_clean_rwos)
print "Num To Clean Rows: " + str(num_to_clean_rows)
print "Num To Add Ext_Ref: " + str(num_to_add_ext_refs)
print "Num Dirty Rows: " + str(num_dirty_rows)
print "Num Hansi Iterations: " + str(num_hansi_iterations)
print "Num Mediahub Iterations: " + str(num_mediahub_iterations / num_hansi_iterations)

# Writing clean_assets to a file
wdw_clean_assets = []

with open('wdw_clean_assets.csv', 'w') as wdw_clean_assets:
    writer = csv.writer(wdw_clean_assets)
    for row in clean_assets:
        writer.writerow([row])

wdw_clean_assets.close()

wdw_to_add_ext_refs =[]

with open('wdw_to_add_ext_refs.csv', 'w') as wdw_to_add_ext_refs:
    writer = csv.writer(wdw_to_add_ext_refs)
    for row in to_add_ext_refs:
        writer.writerow([row])

wdw_to_clean_assets = []

with open('wdw_to_clean_assets.csv', 'w') as wdw_to_clean_assets:
    writer = csv.writer(wdw_to_clean_assets)
    for row in to_clean_assets:
        writer.writerow([row])

wdw_to_clean_assets.close()

wdw_hansi_assets_rest = []

with open('wdw_hansi_assets_rest.csv', 'w') as wdw_hansi_assets_rest:
    writer = csv.writer(wdw_hansi_assets_rest)
    for row in hansi_assets_rest:
        writer.writerow([row])

wdw_hansi_assets_rest.close()

wdw_mediahub_assets_rest = []

with open('wdw_mediahub_assets_rest.csv', 'w') as wdw_mediahub_assets_rest:
    writer = csv.writer(wdw_mediahub_assets_rest)
    for row in mediahub_assets_rest:
        writer.writerow([row])

wdw_mediahub_assets_rest.close()
```

Any help appreciated!

Manuel

Comment: These long questions with a lot of irrelevant information tend to repel users. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question. Otherwise chances are that the question is put on hold, because it is unclear, what you are asking.

Comment: Irrelevant information? I did this on purpose to make clear what it's all about. If I could have made it simpler, I've done it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: The point of "minimal, complete, verifiable" is to break it down into problems that people can easily answer. Ask each problem individually (there seem to be here at least two). Complex problems tend to be ignored as you have experienced with your last question. Add toy input and output data, which have the same problem, instead of your real ones, so users can reproduce the error and suggest solutions. Use simple variable names. `all_lines.csv` tells the reader more than `wdw_clip_db_2018-01-17_2.csv`.

Comment: I understand. But this means I need to know where the problems are and I don't know. My Script takes several minutes, 15 or more to complete, so there seams to be a looping problem I guess. But that's it.